# Start async tasks on app start, await on later button click

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

I have a Windows 10 UWP application that I want to start intialising some classes asap, and only later need them to be complete.

I am new to multithreaded programming so apologies for apparent stupidity of my approach.

I started a task in the App constructor, assigning the task to a static property:

```
sealed partial class App : Application {
    ...
    internal static Task CoreIntialisationTask { get; set; }

    public App() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        CoreIntialisationTask = StartInitialisation();

        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    private async Task StartInitialisation() {
        await InitialiseService1Async();
        var service2Task = this.InitializeService2Async();
        var service3Task = this.InitializeService3Async();
        await service2Task;
        await service3Task;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in my first loaded page, on a button click, is the latest possible moment when these services need to be fully initialised, so I added a check status and await call:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (App.CoreIntialisationTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
    {
        await App.CoreIntialisationTask;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the CoreIntialisationTask Status at this point is Failure with the following inner Exception:

```
(new System.Threading.Tasks.SystemThreadingTasks_FutureDebugView<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>(App.CoreIntialisationTask).Exception).InnerException.Message
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.get_Resources()
at MyApplication.App.<InitializeService>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at MyApplication.App.<StartInitialisation>d__25.MoveNext()
```

The `StartInitialisation()` method seems to get to the `await service2Task` but never the `await service3Task;` line.

Am I approaching this completely the wrong way or is there something more minor I am missing here?

Comment: Apparently some of the COM components your initialization functions use can only be instantiated on the UI thread... so try creating the Task from a Loaded event on your page, instead of the App's constructor.

Comment: Or in the `OnLaunched` method. AFAIK it's running on UI thread too.

Comment: Thank you Ben - your response led to the solution. Just moving the code to the OnLaunched method of the App class solved the issue. 

I didn't realise there were some things that could only be done on a UI thread. My service initialisations do some file IO, initialise a scanner, and start GPS tracking.

Comment: Does anyone know why my question has been marked down? Please be honest - I don't want to be wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check server status or process.
If you need server you can use like:

```
Public Sub StratServices(ByVal servername As String)
    Try
        Dim service As ServiceController = New ServiceController(servername)
        If service.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
            service.Start()
            service.Refresh()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You dont have Sql Srver in your Machine")
    End Try
End Sub

By use System.Serviceprocess
```